# php mkdir will only work when creating a folder inside a 777 folder

Tags: php, mkdir

I have a folder called 'folders'. I want to create a folder inside 'folders' called 'folder' with `mkdir()`

However the folder fails to create when 'folders' is set to 755. The only may I can get mkdir to work is making 'folders' 777. Is this typical or is there something else wrong? Shouldn't be able to do that on 755, isn't 777 a security risk?

Comment: You need to provide information about the directory ownership and the account you are using to create the directories.

Comment: [Unix Permissions](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php). as the link says in one of the tables further down 755 = *"The file's owner may read, write, and execute the file. All others may read and execute the file. This setting is common for programs that are used by all users."* meaning only the owner of that folder can write stuff inside it. everyone else can only read and execute. 777 has no restrictions

Comment: I checked the error logs and the error is "Permission denied". So how do I give PHP the same access that SSH has? I created the 'folders' directory with SSH.

Answer (score 0):

A 777 permission on the directory means that *everyone* has access to read/write/execute (execute on a directory means that you can do a ls of the directory).

Try this one below if you fails to create folder inside the folder.

```
   <?php
    // Desired folder structure
    $structure = './folders/folder/';

    // To create the nested structure, the $recursive parameter 
    // to mkdir() must be specified.

    if (!mkdir($structure, 0755, true)) {
        die('Failed to create folders...');
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately setting recursive to 'true' doesn't work either. I checked the error logs and the error is "Permission denied". So how do I give PHP the same access that SSH has? I created the 'folders' directory with SSH.

Comment: Have you tried to chown the folder where you want to create folder?

`chown -R o+w foldername/`

Comment: I'm new to this. When I do that the response is "invalid user".
The issue is PHP does have permission to write to this folder and I have no idea how to enable write permission for PHP